# Create scheduled task GPO using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks, gpo

I want to set up a GPO which apply to all the computers in my Active Directory domain.
For some reason, I need to create this GPO using a PowerShell script.

I didn't find much information on Google, but it seems that I need to use registry keys, with the PowerShell applet `Set-GPregistryValue`.

I tried to create the GPO using registry keys, something like that:

```
$GPOName = "run-custom-script"
$GPOPath = "OU=Computers,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=local"
$TaskName = "My Scheduled Task"
$TaskDescription = "This task runs a PowerShell script."
$TaskExecutable = "powershell.exe"
$TaskArguments = "-File C:\MyScript.ps1"
$TaskTrigger = "AtLogon"
$TaskEnabled = "1"

New-GPO -Name $GPOName
$GPO = Get-GPO -Name $GPOName
New-GPLink -Name $GPOName -Target $GPOPath
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Task Scheduler\Tasks\$TaskName" -ValueName "Description" -Type String -Value $TaskDescription
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Task Scheduler\Tasks\$TaskName" -ValueName "Executable" -Type String -Value $TaskExecutable
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Task Scheduler\Tasks\$TaskName" -ValueName "Arguments" -Type String -Value $TaskArguments
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Task Scheduler\Tasks\$TaskName" -ValueName "Trigger" -Type String -Value $TaskTrigger
Set-GPRegistryValue -Name $GPOName -Key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Task Scheduler\Tasks\$TaskName" -ValueName "Enabled" -Type String -Value $TaskEnabled
```

Unfortunately the task does not appear on tasks scheduler on the client computers, even after reboot or `gpupdate /force`.

I know that I'm using the correct `$GPOPath` as other GPOs are working with this same `$GPOPath`.

I'm also aware that scheduled tasks can be exported as XML files. Could it be possible to import XML file inside the GPO, still using PowerShell ?

Comment: What account is being used to start task?  Event viewer only shows processes started by the user and system.  Do you see task if you open Event Viewer as an Admin?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. There is actually no scheduled task, even as admin (I suppose it is created as domain administrator). And even if this task was created as an other user, I think it should be still visible in the task scheduler ?

Comment: You need permission to run the task.  Windows does allow one user to run another users task automatically.  You may need to setup a Group Account to allow the task to be run by more than one user.

Comment: Ok, thank you, understood ! I'm trying to first create a scheduled task GPO using GUI in order to use it as an xml template, as explained in the @UncleCisco's answer. The only constraint is to run the task as a domain user, even if it is a local user logged in on the target computer. I do not need to have admin privileges, but I prefer to avoid creating a new domain account just for this specific case.

Comment: There may be a group account that you can use.  If you are on a corporate network Group Policies exist and you can use one of the existing groups.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the registry keys will not do.
To create a scheduled task on a Windows computer it takes more than just registry keys.
You can create them using a PowerShell script, using the '*-ScheduledTask*' cmdlets, or using the 'Schedule.Service' COM object.
To edit such features on a GPO programmatically, try editing the GPO XML.
Create a 'model' GPO which produce the desired results.
Use the 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' to import it into PowerShell.

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Path\To\GPO.xml)
```

Edit the object and save it.
Here's the documentation on these classes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=net-7.0

I hope it helps.
Happy scripting!

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this helps me ! Do I need to use `Backup-GPO` and `Import-GPO` for this purpose ? If yes, there are two `xml` files generated and some other files. Which of them should I edit ?

Comment: I've never done this before, but I'd totally do Backup-GPO first so you don't mess the production one. About the XML, I'm not quite sure, you can create one using the GUI and mimic it.